# Custom Spinner With Buttons

Tags: android

I am wanting to create a custom Android spinner such that there are 2 buttons at the bottom of the pop-open list.  These buttons will cause another popup.  I see two possible methods for creating the buttons.  As I am still new to Android I don't know which is better or perhaps there is a third method?

1) In the adapter class, getCustomView() method, return a layout with two buttons in it for the last item in the list.  This seems awkward to me.  And it pretty much forces me to put the adapter in the view object so that I can control it.

2) Create a totally new custom view object.  This seems like a lot of work since the spinner is pretty close to what I need already.

3) ?

I am looking for some expert Android developer opinions.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through the following code which I made for custom spinner:
[Spinner custom layout keep default layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917870/spinner-custom-layout-keep-default-layout/18918037#18918037)

Comment: Thanks for responding!